# Set background image in html template

Tags: html

I want to set background image in html template. Image size is 1600 x 1200. I want to set background image as fixed. When screen size smaller(zoom in and out email template), many image occurs in email template. I want to set background image as one image without depending on screen size of computer in html template. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 
.imgcon
{
    background-image: url("http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/wwfeatures/wm/live/1280_640/images/live/p0/3x/sw/p03xsw49.jpg");
 width: 1600px;
 height: 1200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position: center top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
 color:white;

}
```

```html
<div class="imgcon">

This is a div that has a fixed background. This text will overlap on the top of the background image. 

</div>
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please consider selecting my answer as a solution to the presented issue by ticking the right check mark next to the voting arrows. Thanks.